# json_decode return NULL when we use cloud convert web services

Tags: php, json, drupal-7

I am using cloud convert API to convert video. When i hit it's purl URL using curl_exec(), it returns json output

```
 {"id":"F024KteuEliCgA9TLMxh","url":"//hostiorg3y.cloudconvert.com/process/F024KteuEliCgA9TLMxh","percent":100,"message":"Uploaded file to S3 Bucket","step":"finished","starttime":1445239854,"expire":1445283060,"input":{"type":"s3","filename":"newvideo_0.mp4","name":"newvideo_0","ext":"mp4","size":1089552,"url":"//hostiorg3y.cloudconvert.com/download/F024KteuEliCgA9TLMxh/input"},"output":{"url":"//hostiorg3y.cloudconvert.com/download/F024KteuEliCgA9TLMxh","save":true,"ext":"mpg","filename":"newvideo_0.mpg","size":1685504,"type":"s3"},"converter":{"format":"mpg","type":"ffmpeg","options":{"video_codec":"MPEG2VIDEO","video_bitrate":"1024","audio_codec":"MP3","audio_bitrate":"128","audio_frequency":"44100","audio_qscale":"5"},"duration":14.98},"group":"video","endtime":1445239860,"minutes":1}
```

But When i use json_decode() function to decode it. it returns NULL.

Comment: You may want to enable error notifications to diagnose the problem. ini_set('display_errors', True);

Comment: Can you try to trim your JSON? E.g. `$json = trim($json);` ?

Comment: I use both json-last-error-msg and json_last_error but both return  No error.

Comment: i use trim(), utf8_decode() function as well.

Comment: Odd just tried it in online functions - seems to be ok there, mm. trim, check got the correct variable going into the function - check with an echo before. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php couple of  common mistakes with json - are you in one of those problems?